# How to properly copy/clone DOM element and then paste/insert it as HTML element in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, dom, coffeescript, angularjs-ng-repeat, clone

So I've got such big webapp that uses Angular.js.
Small part of this webapp has sidebar which, currently, displays two div containers: one that shows user profile stats (thumbnail, reputation, messages, some skills .etc) and second which is slider (angular-ui) carousel showing some images.

What I want to do, is to clone this whole skills sidebar and paste this cloned DOM object into slider as another slide, but converted into HTML element.

Here's code of this slider:

```
<div id="scrolling-sidebar">
  <carousel interval="myInterval">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
      <a href="{{slide.link}}" ng-if="$index != 1">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" />
      </a>
      <a href="{{slide.link}}" ng-bind-html="slide.content"></a>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

Here's part of this whole sidebar controller .coffee script:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('someApp')
  .controller 'SidebarCtrl', ($scope, $modal, $http, $location, settings) ->


    $scope.myInterval = 5000
    $scope.slides = [
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners1.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            content: $("#profile-skills-sidebar").clone()
            link: "#/get-pro" 
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners2.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners3.png"
            link: "#/get-noticed"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners4.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners5.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners6.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners7.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
    ]
    console.log "Cloned dom element: " + $scope.slides[1].content[0].html()
```

When running this webapp (basically refreshing webpage), I get following error in developer console: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' at new <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9000/scripts/controllers/sidebar.js:39:69) of undefined` which corresponds to this line `console.log("Cloned dom element: " + $scope.slides[1].content[0].html());` in compiled to js sidebar.js file.

So this basically means, that this line `content: $("#profile-skills-sidebar").clone()` doesn't work like intended - it looks like the DOM element isn't even cloned.

Thus, second slide is `[object Object]` instead copied skills bar.

I got jQuery loaded in  (using bower and grunt for frontend development), I can use in while in browser devtools:

```
> var skills = $("#profile-skills-sidebar");
< undefined
> skills
< [<div id="profile-skills-sidebar">…</div>]
> skills[0]
< <div id="profile-skills-sidebar">…</div>
```

I tried creating directive in .coffee script:

```
.directive "skillsBarSlide", ['$compile', ($scope, $compile, $timeout) ->
    restrict: 'A'
    #template: '<a href="{{slide.link}}"></a>'
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        $timeout( -> 
            scope.slides[1].content = angular.element($("#profile-skills-sidebar")).copy()
            element.append($compile(scope.slides[1].content)(scope))
        )
  ]
```

but it didn't worked.

So what steps precisely I have to make to:
1. clone needed DOM element
2. Probably convert it to string of HTML elements (because cloned DOM will be an object)
3. Insert into desired div container

I know that I need here probably $sce, $compile maybe $sanitize (I've read the angular docs a bit), but I'm fresh to angular, didn't understood it well yet.

Thanks for eventual help.

Comment: Nobody knows?
I'll try with `$("#profile-skills-sidebar").html()` or `angular.copy($("#profile-skills-sidebar"))` instead, maybe this will help.
Or, try with just manually pasting html of this skillsbar as a value of `content:` and then use `$sce.trustAsHtml(copiedHtml)`, maybe this will help.
I'll let know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so finally made it, my way.

*sidebar.coffee*:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('someApp')
  .controller 'SidebarCtrl', ($scope, $sce, $modal, $http, $location, settings) ->


    $scope.myInterval = 5000
    $scope.slides = [
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners1.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            content: ''
            link: "#/get-pro" 
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners2.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners3.png"
            link: "#/get-noticed"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners4.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners5.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners6.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
        {
            image: "/images/_getpro_banners7.png"
            link: "#/get-pro"
        }
    ]

    [...]some_code[...]

    $scope.renderHTML = ->
        $scope.slides[1].content = "<div id='profile-skills-sidebar'>" + $("#profile-skills-sidebar").clone().html() + "</div>"
        #console.log "Cloned dom element: " + $scope.slides[1].content
        $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.slides[1].content)
```

*sidebar.html*:

```
<div id="scrolling-sidebar" ng-hide="{{hasPro}}">
  <carousel interval="myInterval">
    <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
      <a href="{{slide.link}}" ng-if="$index != 1">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" />
      </a>
      <a href="{{slide.link}}" class="skills-bar-slide" ng-if="$index == 1" ng-bind-html="renderHTML()"></a>
    </slide>
  </carousel>
</div>
```

So, HTML element had to be pulled from DOM element cloned as JS object, using `.html()` jQuery/jqLite function.
Then using [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)'s, **trustAsHtml()** method, validate this HTML code for *ng-bind-html* directive.
And basically that's all.